# Unsure why i am getting Missing Number treated as Zero error

Tags: errors, formatting

I only know the basics of latex and for some reason I am now getting the following error.

> !Missing number, treated as zero.
>
> \let \centering.

The beginning on my code is as follows:

```
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
\textheight
\centering
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error for the `\centering` line and because of this I am unable to complete quick builds.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove that `\textheight`. It is a length, it will have no effect where it is in your code.

Answer (score 3):

The error is because of the `\textheight` in your code. You can't use it like that.

`\textheight` is a length, which is how TeX represents real-valued variables. When you use a variable like that (either real-valued, like `\textheight` or integer, like `\c@page`), TeX is expecting that you will do an assignment. That is, you will store a value in that variable (exactly like in other programming languages), but it never finds the value it was looking for and says `Missing number` when it finds the first illegal token (in this context), which in this case is the `\let` token after it expanded `\centering`:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.7 \centering
?
```

which is precisely the cause of the error. If you insert a number (`1cm`, for example) after the `\textheight` the code will compile correctly and the value of `\textheight` would change to `1cm`. P.S.: Don't do that :)

If you want to *print the value* of `\textheight` you can use `\the`:

```latex
\the\textheight
```

which is TeX's primitive to access the value of a register.

Comment: Unless there is no vote for your answer the question still counts as 'unanswered'.... oops, there is a vote ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks `:)`. To be honest, I answered more to see if someone knows why TeX expects a length after the `\textheight`. I have never seen this, and it got me curious...

Comment: You can set a TeX length by saying `\textheight 2cm`, which is what TeX expects when it finds a length without any special context. (The syntax used in the TeXbook is `\textheight=2cm`, but the `=` is not necessary.)

Comment: @schtandard If one want to change the `\textwidth`, yes, but what OP seems to want is to print the value (though we will never know for sure). The TeXbook syntax actually says (pages 275 and 276) that a `⟨variable assignment⟩ → ⟨dimen variable⟩⟨equals⟩⟨dimen⟩` and `⟨equals⟩ → ⟨optional spaces⟩ | ⟨optional spaces⟩=₁₂`, which means that a catcode 12 `=` is an optional part of the assignment syntax.

Comment: Sure. I was trying to point out why TeX expects a length after `\textheight` (because it expects an assignment), since you requested that information. (Though I now see that this question is much older than I first thought.)

Comment: @schtandard Ooh. Now that I read my answer you comment makes much more sense. At the time I wrote this I was pretty TeX-illiterate. Good times :-) I'll update this. Thanks anyhow :D